# Openings and Closings (Salutations and Valedictions) When Writing a Letter/E-mail

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

This question came to me because I am writing a personal thank-you letter to a friend's family who hosted me in their home over the holidays.  What is the proper way to address the entire family?  For example, in English, I would use "To the Ito Family".  Beyond this, it would be good to compile a list of typical Japanese openings and closings (salutations and valedictions) used in written correspondence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For letters to a person, affix it with 様. For Itou family, it would be イトウ(御)一家様. For letters to a company or institution, affix it with 御中.